# BATCH: use variable declared in another folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I must create a script that works with different variables. They are either names ("my name"), either addresses( 123.45.6.789 ).

Is it possible to have a file "variables.txt" in which I've declared all those variables and then use them in my .bat script ? Both the file and the script will be located within the same directory.
Or else, how could I read them ? (I mention that I'm really new to batch, as I just started learning it for my task )

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read the file you can use something like this:

```
for %%a in ('type vars.txt') do (
for "delims=;" %%m in ("%%a") do (
set %%m=%%n
)
)
```

Sorry, but i couldn't test this, because i'm not writing from my PC.